# After subsetting data frame, functions do not work on subset

Tags: r

My initial dataset was a csv containing information about the number of bikes that were rented in a certain city with other variables being temperature,season, etc...

I was creating a subset based on conditionals to get a set that would have seasons be "3" or "4" and annee be "1". I tried the following:

`P<- subset(velo,saison>2&annee==1)`

I also tried

`W<- velo[which(velo$annee==1 & velo$saison>2),]`

Which both returned the same dataframe/subset of 183 obs 5 variables

I then wanted to summarise the data through

```
summary(W$velos[saison==3])
summary(W$velos[saison==4])
```

[It gives me the following outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq9N6.png)

In the data set I can see that the column season is not full of NaN and doing the class() returns integer for that column.

Comment: Try with `subset(velo, saison %in% c(3, 4)  & annee == 1)`  Looking at the `summary` code, should it be `summary(W$velos[W$saison == 3])`

Comment: @akrun You mean `%in%`?

Comment: Hi, still getting the same output when I use the summary() function. the exact same thing unfortunately..

Comment: @doofungu  I think you wanted `W$saison` instead of `saison`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of not extracting the column

```
summary(W$velos[W$saison==3])
```